# External Library

Tags: c++, gcc

How do you make .h files globally accessible by for example #include ? If its compiler specific either migw or gcc. C++

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the "-I" option to the compiler -- this will add a directory to the include-file search path.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I do, is install headers in

> /i686-pc-mingw32/include

libs in

> /i686-pc-mingw32/lib

and dll's in

> /i686-pc-mingw32/bin

and add that last one to PATH (so relevant dll's will be found by programs you build).

For mingw-w64 switch `i686-pc-mingw32` with either `i686-w64-mingw32` (32-bit) or `x86_64-w64-mingw32` (64-bit).

This allows #include to find the file without any additional -I switches. It is identical to a make install on linux (in most simple cases).

Comment: The -I solution is a lot more general. Copying arbitrary files to your default include path seems like a bad idea in general.